# The type arguments for method Queryable.Select cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I am using a `LambdaExpression` to select columns dynamically:

```
var property = "power_usage"; // I set this dynamically.
var entityType = typeof(system_state);
var prop = entityType.GetProperty(property);
var source = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "ss");

var func = typeof(Func<,>);
var genericFunc = func.MakeGenericType(typeof(system_state), prop.PropertyType);

var linqQuery = context.system_state
            .Where(ss => ss.time_stamp >= StartDate && ss.time_stamp <= EndDate)
            .Select(genericFunc, Expression.PropertyOrField(source, property), source);
```

The variable `genericFunc` is supposed to define the `delegateType`, but I still get this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's very hard to help you without a full concrete example. (I'd suggest using `List<T>` and `AsQueryable` to reproduce this.)

Comment: What is in your genericFunc, body and source variables....

Comment: The non generic version of `Expression.Lambda` cannot be used directly.

Comment: I've updated the question with more code. `system_state` is a database table that was created with Entity Framework.

Comment: `Select` needs to know the **type** of the result, which in this case is the type of the property. If you don't know the type of the property, what do you expect to be the type of the result - i.e. `IQueryable<???>`

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, I understand, but that is why I set the `delegateType` to a `<Func<TSource, TResult>>` using `genericFunc`. In the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350515(v=vs.110).aspx) it says that it is supposed to return a `Expression<TDelegate>` object. Have I understood it wrong?

Comment: The problem is that `TResult` needs to be known at *compile time*, so `linqQuery` to be `IQueryable<string>`, or `IQueryable<int>` etc. It's not possible to resolve the type of `var` at runtime. It's possible to emit the call to `Select` dynamically, but all you can get will be a non generic `IQueryable`, which is not so useful. You might take a look at DynamicLINQ package to see how it is addressing this and similar problems. But even with it it's a pain to work with untyped `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll quote @Ivan Stoev

> The problem is that `TResult` needs to be known at compile time, so `linqQuery` (must) be `IQueryable<string>`, or `IQueryable<int>` etc. It's not possible to resolve the type of `var` at runtime. It's possible to emit the call to `Select` dynamically, but all you can get will be a non generic `IQueryable`, which is not so useful. You might take a look at DynamicLINQ package to see how it is addressing this and similar problems. But even with it it's a pain to work with untyped `IQueryable`.

Then if you really want to do it... In the end it is your code :-)

This can be cached:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo selectT = (from x in typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                                                where x.Name == nameof(Queryable.Select) && x.IsGenericMethod
                                                let gens = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                                where gens.Length == 2
                                                let pars = x.GetParameters()
                                                where pars.Length == 2 &&
                                                    pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(gens[0]) &&
                                                    pars[1].ParameterType == typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(gens))
                                                select x).Single();
```

Then:

```
var property = "power_usage"; // I set this dynamically.
var entityType = typeof(system_state);
var prop = entityType.GetProperty(property);
var source = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "ss");

var func = typeof(Func<,>);
var genericFunc = func.MakeGenericType(typeof(system_state), prop.PropertyType);

var baseQuery = context.system_state
            .Where(ss => ss.time_stamp >= StartDate && ss.time_stamp <= EndDate);

var exp = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(source, prop), source);

MethodInfo select = selectT.MakeGenericMethod(entityType, prop.PropertyType);

IQueryable query = (IQueryable)select.Invoke(null, new object[] { baseQuery, exp });

var result = query.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Note that I'm obtaining a non-generic `IQueryable`... Then I cast its elements to `object` and do a `ToArray()`, but you can do whatever you want with it. Underneath the `IQueryable` will be strongly typed, so it will be a `IQueryable<int>` or a `IQueryable<something>`, so you can cast it back to the "real" interface (`IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IQueryable`)